# VC Merge Modules Not Updating

Tags: merge-module, vc8, vc90

I posted an issue a while back:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123872/visual-c-runtime-8-0-50727-6910-merge-module

where I had an issue that I could find a particular version of a merge module.

I have since attempted to reinstall SP1 of both Visual Studio 2005 and 2008, and the merge modules for both runtimes (8 and 9) are not correctly being updated in (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules).  The only VC merge modules there are the original 8 and 9 modules.

I am running Windows 8 Enterprise x64.  Does anyone know any of any issues with VC8/9 merge modules not being updated correctly through the Visual Studio update process on Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with me application.

I added merge modules for Redist VC 90 in my setup project. works in Windows XP, Vista &  7. But it wasn't installed in Windows 8.

I've installed it manually (redist exe) and worked. Issue in w8?